# Compare two columns using the contains predicate

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have a Core Data entity with two columns: `artistName`, of type String, and a relationship with another entity which has a column `name`, also of type String.

I can create a predicate which compares these two columns like so:

```
NSPredicate(format: "artistName == artist.name")
```

So for a row with `artistName = Beyoncé` and `artist.name = Beyoncé`, this predicate returns true.

But, if I change it to use `contains`, it doesn't work:

```
NSPredicate(format: "artistName contains artist.name")
```

The code above results in this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (artistName CONTAINS artist.name) (LHS and RHS both keypaths)'

I want to use `contains` to create a predicate that would return true for a row with `artistName = Beyoncé feat. Jay-Z` and `artist.name = Beyoncé`, for example.

How can a compare two columns using the `contains` predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot written on the use of predicates. While it is a few years ago now... [a very good article](https://nshipster.com/nspredicate/) from NSHipster.

Here are some links to the Apple Documentation:

- [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate);
- [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795);
- [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789).

The answer to your question lies in the error message *LHS and RHS both keypaths*.

You *have* written a simple predicate as:

NSPredicate(format: KEYPATH *comparator* KEYPATH)

In your case, you *should* write a simple predicate as:

NSPredicate(format: KEYPATH *comparator* VALUE)

---

### UPDATE

I was attempting to keep my answer short, to encourage the OP to develop an understanding of predicate syntax... however perhaps more explanation is required...

You have a Core Data entity that I'm guessing is named `Artist` with the following:

- attribute of type `String` and name `artistName`;
- relationship of type `Artist` (guessing?) and name `name`.

You want to check whether both `artistName` and `name` contain the `String` "Beyoncé".

How can you do that with one comparison??? In my humble opinion, impossible.

You need two comparisons:

- check whether the value for attribute `artistName` contains "Beyoncé";
- check whether the value for relationship `name` contains "Beyoncé".

So how do you write a "compare" predicate with two comparisons?

There are a number of ways to do this.

In the longer term, I'd encourage you to investigate the power of `NSCompoundPredicate` as I am certain it will serve you well in the future.

In the meantime, you can write a "two comparison" predicate using the following syntax...

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(artistName contains 'Beyoncé') AND (name.artistName contains 'Beyoncé')")
```

or dynamically / generically...

```
let keypath1: String = "artistName"
let keypath2: String = "name.artistName"
let value: String = "Beyoncé"

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%K contains %@) AND (%K contains %@)", argumentArray: [keypath1, value, keypath2, value])
```

NOTES:

- you do have to traverse the relationship; and
- you may need to write as `contains[cd]` to make the comparison case-insensitive and diacritic-insensitive, thereby dealing with characters such as "é".

You may see now that in your question, the first `==` comparator works only because you are literally comparing two implied string values. The second `contains` does not work because predicate syntax rules expect the second argument to be a value (LHS a keypath and RHS a value). Swift is reading the second `contains` as "attribute `artistName` contains the entity associated with the relationship `name`"

Diego Freniche built a [playground](https://github.com/dfreniche/NSPredicate-Swift) to demonstrate the use of predicates... maybe worth looking at for practical examples? 
(https://github.com/dfreniche/NSPredicate-Swift)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and reference links!